# Using GCP Workflow CallBack for receive SMS message using Twilio

Tags: google-cloud-platform, twilio, google-workflows

I am exploring GCP Workflow. I would like to send an SMS message  and wait for the response from the user. I know that GCP workflow is able to receive a callback, but i didn't find way to wire up this execution flow.

I suppose that I need to store state in a database with the phone number, a timeout period and the callback. If the message comes from the same phone number and it's below the timeout period, I should call the callback function.

It's seems a commom use case, and I know that I could handle with twilio flow. But it's complex to maintain and evolve twilio flows.

Comment: I don't know twilio, but if you can't provide the callback url during the 1st SMS submission, you have to do the match on your side. Store the call back URL and the data that will send you back twilio to make the match in your generic callback handler and then call the correct callback URL